# Swift and @objc methods: How do I transform a method so that it can be represented by @objc?

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, methods

As Swift is my first programming language and also seeing that I have no Objective C experience...
I'm having difficulty understanding @objc in relation to methods.

How do I use the @objc syntax to conform to my methods?
Is there another way to select a method without using the #selector syntax?

Here is the code that I'm having difficulty with(mainly the @objc attempt at the startGame method):

```
import UIKit

@objc class ViewController: UITableViewController {
var allWords = [String]()
var usedWords = [String]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: 
#selector(promptForAnswer))
    
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New 
Word", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(startGame))
   
    
    if let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", 
withExtension: "txt") {
        if let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL) {
            allWords = startWords.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        }
    }
    if allWords.isEmpty {
        allWords = ["silkworm"]
    }
    
@objc func startGame() {
        title = allWords.randomElement()  
        usedWords.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true) 
        tableView.reloadData() 
    {
    startGame()
    }
```

Comment: You're omitting a lot of important information here (or I assume you are). `startGame` needs to be defined at the same level as your other functions -- your current code makes it look as if it is nested *inside* another function. If that's the case, that's your issue. If that's not the case, please show the code it the structure as it appears in your real code.

Comment: Yeah  I did omit a lot of info there.  I updated the code. I dont think my method is nested here. Let me know if i should include some more code. Thanks!!

Comment: Still looks to me like `func startGame()` is *inside* `viewDidLoad`. It needs to be its own function at the same level as `viewDidLoad` -- not inside it.

Comment: Between `["silkworm"]` and `@objc` should be two `}}` not one `}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You do not need `@objc` in your view controller declaration.
2. The two action/selector methods should bear `@objc` qualifier.
3. I would suggest that you give these two methods descriptive names that clearly indicate that they are called when the user taps on a particular button, e.g.:

   ```swift
   @objc func didTapNewWord(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       ...
   }

   @objc func didTapAdd(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   Note, I also added a parameter to these methods. That makes it entirely unambiguous that they are button handlers. You do not need to do that, but now you can glance at the code and immediately grok what the method is for.

   Obviously, you will change the code that adds these target actions accordingly:

   ```swift
   navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add,
                                                       target: self,
                                                       action: #selector(didTapAdd(_:)))

   navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New Word",
                                                      style: .plain,
                                                      target: self,
                                                      action: #selector(didTapNewWord(_:)))
   ```
4. Be careful with the placement of braces. Swift allows you to declare functions inside functions. So make sure that these selector methods are instance methods of the view controller, and not, for example, private functions declared inside another function (i.e. `viewDidLoad`).

   If you start to lose track of the braces, you can select all the code in this file and press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> (or in Xcode menus, “Editor” » “Structure” » “Re-Indent”). If you have missing braces somewhere, the re-indentation of the code will make this jump out at you.

---

So pulling that together, you get something like:

```swift
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {
    var allWords = [String]()
    var usedWords = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureButtons()
        fetchData()
    }
}

// MARK: - Actions

extension ViewController {
    @objc func didTapNewWord(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        startGame()
    }

    @objc func didTapAdd(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        ...
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

extension ViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        ...
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ...
    }
}

// MARK: - Private utility methods

private extension ViewController {
    func configureButtons() {
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add,
                                                            target: self,
                                                            action: #selector(didTapAdd(_:)))

        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New Word",
                                                           style: .plain,
                                                           target: self,
                                                           action: #selector(didTapNewWord(_:)))
    }

    func fetchData() {
        guard
            let startWordsURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "start", withExtension: "txt"),
            let startWords = try? String(contentsOf: startWordsURL).components(separatedBy: "\n"),
            !startWords.isEmpty
        else {
            allWords = ["silkworm"]
            return
        }

        allWords = startWords.filter { !$0.isEmpty }
    }

    func startGame() {
        title = allWords.randomElement()
        usedWords.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

---

A few final observations on my code sample (not directly related to your question, but just to explain why structured it like I did):

- I like to put methods into extensions, so that they are in logical groups. This makes it easier to follow what is going on at a glance. You can also collapse/expand these extensions so that while you are editing, you can focus on the relevant code.
- The `MARK` comments just puts nice section headers in the Xcode jump bar, again, making it easier to jump about in one’s code.
- I personally don't put anything in the action methods except a call to some method with the “business logic”. This separates the “view” code (the handling of the button) from the business logic. Some day, you may start using view models or presenter objects, so embracing this separation of responsibilities now will make that eventual transition easier. It will also make it easier to write unit tests when you get around to that (e.g. you write unit tests for the "start game" logic, not not the tapping of a button).

Comment: Amazing thank you for the detailed response.

Comment: I definitely need to work on organizing my code better. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score -1):

I think you have syntax error in the @objc method. It should be:

```
@objc
func functionName() {
}
```

for you it will be:

```
@objc
func startGame() {
        title = allWords.randomElement()  
        usedWords.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true) 
        tableView.reloadData() 
   }
```